# Find the number closest to 0, breaking ties in favor of positive numbers

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, perl

I'm a Perl beginner, I really love this language, and I was wondering if it was possible to reduce the size of this code, just for fun and so as to learn Perl specificities:

```
chomp($n=<STDIN>);
if (!$n) {
   print 0;   
} else {
   @t=split/ /,<STDIN>;
   foreach $i(0..$n-1) {
      $m=$t[$i]if(!$m)||(abs($t[$i])<abs($m))||(($t[$i]==-$m)&&($t[$i]>0));    
   }
}print $m;
```

The goal of this code is to give the closest number to 0 of a list, and if there are -4 and 4 for example, it will always return the positive number.

- `$n` is the number of numbers in the list
- `@t` is the list as an array
- `$m` is the min

This is "Temperatures" game on the website [Codingame.com](https://www.codingame.com/games/puzzles).

This code is working pretty well, and I'm trying to reduce its size so as to discover some Perl secrets.

I have some precise questions:

1. Is it possible to use the ternary operator with several instructions in Perl?
2. Is is possible to write the `foreach` loop on one line in this case, or even replace the `foreach` loop with something else?

I don't really want perfect code as an answer, but some indications, and then I can search details and learn by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A bad example

Perl is a language in which the shortest code is usually not the best code.  For example, this short program accomplishes the task:

```
print((sort {abs($a)<=>abs($b) || $b<=>$a} (split ' ',<>)[0..<>-1])[0] // 0)
```

Not only is it hard to read, it's also algorithmically inefficient (because sorting is O(*n* log *n*) rather than O(*n*)).  I don't recommend writing code like that.

### Critique

You should use more whitespace.  It won't make your code look any less clever, nor will it make your code run any slower.

You can safely dispense with `chomp()`, as Perl will naturally disregard the trailing newline when interpreting the string as a number.  You could probably write `<>` instead of `<STDIN>`, unless you insist on reading only from standard input.

Counting loops are clumsy in Perl.  When possible, opt for higher-level list-processing techniques.  In this case, I recommend [`List::Util::reduce`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%24result-%3d-reduce-%7b-BLOCK-%7d-%40list).

### A possible solution

In Perl, there are usually many possible ways to solve a problem.  Here's one short solution that is O(*n*), but avoids being the shortest possible solution.  I'll let you figure out how it takes advantage of the `<=>` operator.

```
use List::Util qw(max reduce);
use strict;

my $n = <>;
my @temps = (split ' ', <>)[0 .. $n - 1];
print((reduce { ($a, max($a, $b), $b)[1 + (abs($a) <=> abs($b))] } @temps)
       // 0);
```

The special case of `$n == 0` can be handled using a [`//` logical defined-or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or).  A [`||` logical or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or) would also happen to work, but it wouldn't be as appropriate.

Since the `@t` is meant to represent temperatures, renaming it to `@temps` would make the code less cryptic.